# DFS in an adjacency list to find topological ordering

Tags: c

I have been trying to create a program that prints the order in which nodes in a graph are closed during a DFS search. So in the graph 1->2->3 it should print: 3 2 1, somehow the code below would print 3 1 2, in general

for simple graphs like the one above it will print n 1 2 ... n-2 n-1.
If you know what I'm doing wrong please share.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define UNVISITED 0
#define VISITING 1
#define CLOSED 2

typedef struct node{
    int id;
    struct node *next;
}Node;

typedef struct graph{
    int V,E;
    int *visited;
    Node ** list;
    Node* order;
}Graph;

Graph *makeGraph(){
    int v,e,i;
    scanf("%d %d",&v ,&e);
    Graph* g = (Graph*)malloc(sizeof(Graph));
    g->V=v;
    g->E=e;
    g->order =NULL;
    g->list = (Node**)malloc(v*sizeof(Node*));
    g->visited = (int*)malloc(v*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<v;++i){
        g->list[i]=NULL;
        g->visited[i]=UNVISITED;
    }
    return g;
}

void createArcs(Graph *g){
    int from,to;
    Node *n = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    for(int i=0;i<g->E;++i){
        scanf("%d %d",&from ,&to);
        n->id = to;
        n->next = g->list[from-1];
        g->list[from-1]=n;
    }
    return;
}

void visitNode(Graph *g, int i){
    if(g->visited[i]==CLOSED)
        return;
    else if(g->list[i]==NULL){
        printf("%d\t", i+1);
        g->visited[i]=CLOSED;   
        return;
    }
    Node* n = g->list[i];
    while(n!=NULL){
        visitNode(g,n->id-1);
        n=n->next;
    }
    printf("%d\t", i+1);
    g->visited[i]=CLOSED;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    Graph *g = makeGraph();
    createArcs(g);
    for(int i=0;i<g->V;i++)
        visitNode(g,i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What numbers are you entering when you run the program? It would help to have some standard input that we could use to run on our own to test this on our side.